# Oracle Apex - Save list of numbers in a varray-table-field

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, nested-table, varray

I have a table with varray of number field `type aptitude_list as varray(60) of number` and want to save/update a comma separated list from an apex-text-field in it.

My SQL statement looks like :

```
INSERT INTO tbl_aptitude (ID, APTITUDE)
VALUES ('12345678', aptitude_list(1,2,3,4));
```

and works fine in SQL Developer.

Now I want to replace the numbers with my textfield `aptitude_list(:P7_APTITUDE)` with `P7_APTITUDE='1,2,3,4'`. This can´t be saved, because `'1,2,3,4'` is not valid number.

How can I tell the system, that I want to store four different numbers and not one?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [many, many ways](https://web.archive.org/web/20170914140540/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/1968/splitting-delimited-strings#t=201709141405407224393) to split a delimited string in Oracle.

One way is to use a function:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE type aptitude_list as varray(60) of number
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN aptitude_list DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       aptitude_list := aptitude_list();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  p_count        NUMBER(3) := 0;
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE tbl_aptitude (
  ID       VARCHAR2(20),
  APTITUDE aptitude_list
);
```

Then you can use:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_aptitude (ID, APTITUDE)
VALUES ('12345678', split_String(:P7_APTITUDE));
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl_aptitude;
```

**Output**:

```
| ID       | APTITUDE               |
|----------|------------------------|
| 12345678 | APTITUDE_LIST(1,2,3,4) |
```